# Unable to get SBT to download itself from behind Artifactory Pro corporate proxy

Tags: scala, sbt, artifactory

I've configured my local repositories file `~/.sbt/repositories` as follows:

```
[repositories]
local
my-ivy-proxy-releases: http://ourinternalartifactoryaddress.com/artifactory/scala-ivy/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
my-maven-proxy-releases: http://ourinternalartifactoryaddress.com/artifactory/mvn-all
```

Resolution from the `mvn-all` virtual repo seems to work well - this is proxying maven-central as well as a number of internal standard maven repos.  Resolution from `scala-ivy` (a virtual repo) works well for the sbt-plugins remote repo, but it is not working for resolving things like SBT itself.

**The Setup**

`scala-ivy` - virtual repo (package type Ivy) proxying 3 remote repositories:

1. `maven-central-mirror` - (http://central.maven.org/maven2
   )`, this is where sbt *should* be downloading itself from, package type 'Maven'
2. `typesafe-ivy-releases` - the jcenter repo ( https://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/
   ) that houses sbt versions before the 1.x line and a number of Scala artifacts, package type 'Ivy'
3. `scala-sbt` - (https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/
   ), package type 'SBT'

**Question is - what's wrong with this setup/what am I missing on boot?**

Comment: Do you have some kind of trace or log of which artifacts aren't being found and where sbt is trying to retrieve them from? Something besides "it is not working"

Comment: I did, but I'm unable to recreate the problems (they were happening for a week) right now.  All of a sudden, resolving sbt 1.28 via maven-central is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this ended up being a transient issue, but was surprised this morning to see SBT downloading itself from our `mvn-all` virtual repo in Artifactory when historically SBT was in an Ivy repo.

I'm happy to bump up an answer from one of the maintainers on where artifacts live today to help other people setting up.